Check the md5sum of a file with bash
I am currently working on the LFS project along with the book and a video to guide me through some parts of it. However, as I came across checking the MD5 of some packages the verification of this didn't seem to work.
I initially tried this approach, but for some reason the echo "$MD5SUM  $FILENAME" appended the file name to the begging of MD5SUM
if ! echo "$MD5SUM  $FILENAME" | md5sum -c >/dev/null; then
   echo "Verification of $FILENAME failed. MD5 mismatch"
fi

Instead, I tried the following, that despite working perfectly when testing it, didn't work in this particular case
if [[ $(md5sum "$FILENAME" | cut -d ' ' -f1) != "$MD5SUM" ]]; then
      echo "Verification of $FILENAME failed. MD5 mismatch"
fi

As per someone's request the output of md5sum "$FILENAME" | cut -d ' ' -f1 is 590765dee95907dbc3c856f7255bd669. On the other hand, the output from md5sum "$FILENAME" | cut -d ' ' -f1 | cat -A is 590765dee95907dbc3c856f7255bd669$

Please add output of md5sum "$FILENAME" | cut -d ' ' -f1 | cat -A to your question (no comment).

@Cyrus: actually I think we need printf %s "$MD5SUM" | cat -A -- or just printf %q "$MD5SUM". It's that variable that appears to be bad, not the program output.

See Why does my tool output overwrite itself and how do I fix it?.

Use stdin instead of providing the filename
md5sum < "$filename"

so you don't need to cut.
Then you can compare directly.

Wrong! In case of stdin string "  -" must be cut.

As Wiimm says, either cut the dash, or pipe your command through a tr, i.e. md5sum <$filename | tr -d '- '

Assuming that MD5SUM contains the MD5 of file FILENAME,
if ! md5sum -c --quiet <<<"$MD5SUM  $FILENAME"
then
  echo Verification failed
fi

should do the job.
